# How to return the property that contains an error in a single method using INotifyDataErrorInfo?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, idataerrorinfo

**Problem**

I am able to implement a validation for each property with it's own separate method. The problem I have is, this is too much code having too many methods for each property - I am aiming to have all the methods into 1 single method.

I now encountered an issue, on how to identify which property contains an error within my single method.

**Service**

Here I built the service to check the Username and Password from the `User` property.

```
public interface ILoginValidationService
{
    bool ValidateUser(UserModel user, out ICollection<string> errors);
}

public class LoginValidationService : ILoginValidationService
{


    public bool ValidateUser(UserModel user, out ICollection<string> errors)
    {
        errors = new List<string>();
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(user.FirstName))
        {
            errors.Add("First Name cannot be empty");
        }
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(user.LastName))
        {
            errors.Add("Last Name cannot be empty");
        }

        return errors.Count == 0;
    }
}
```

**Actual validation**

Within here, I create 2 methods `Validation` and `ValidateUser` which takes a single parameter of the `UserModel`.

The `Validation` method, creates a new UserModel object, takes the `FirstName` and `LastName` from the public properties that the TextBox is binded to. Then it calls the `ValidateUser(user)` passing the user object.

In `ValidateUser` method, is where I encountered the problem.

This method currently takes the property of `FirstName` `var prop = nameof(FirstName);` just as an example for now.

Next, you'll see the `bool isValid` property, this validates the user.

It does it's validations and returns the errors to `FirstName` mentioned in `var prop = nameof(FirstName);` and here is the output: *SEE IMAGE BELOW CODE*

```
private ILoginValidationService ValidationService { get; set; }
private bool Validation()
{
    UserModel user = new UserModel
    {
        FirstName = FirstName,
        LastName = LastName
    };
    ValidateUser(user);
    return _validationErrors.Count == 0 ? false : true;
}
private void ValidateUser(UserModel user)
{
    var prop = nameof(FirstName);
    ICollection<string> validationErrors = null;
    bool isValid = ValidationService.ValidateUser(user, out validationErrors);

    if (!isValid)
    {
        _validationErrors[prop] = validationErrors;
        RaiseErrorsChanged(prop);
    }
    else if (_validationErrors.ContainsKey(prop))
    {
        _validationErrors.Remove(prop);
        RaiseErrorsChanged(prop);
    }
}

#region INotifyDataErrorInfo members

private readonly Dictionary<string, ICollection<string>> _validationErrors = new Dictionary<string, ICollection<string>>();

public event EventHandler<DataErrorsChangedEventArgs> ErrorsChanged;
private void RaiseErrorsChanged(string propertyName)
{
    if (ErrorsChanged != null)
        ErrorsChanged(this, new DataErrorsChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}

public IEnumerable GetErrors(string propertyName)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyName)
        || !_validationErrors.ContainsKey(propertyName))
        return null;

    return _validationErrors[propertyName];
}

public bool HasErrors
{
    get { return _validationErrors.Count > 0; }
}
#endregion
```

**Output**

[image]

What it does, it displays the erorr below the `FirstName`.

**Question**

Where I currently have `var prop = nameof(FirstName);` how can I determine from `bool isValid = ValidationService.ValidateUser(user, out validationErrors);` which property has the error? And display the error relevant to it's Property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of working with an ICollection and string you could think about creating your own class to report on errors.
Something simple like:

```
class ErrorInformation
{
    public string PropertyName {get;}
    public string Message {get;}
}
```

In ValidateUser instead of adding string to your collection you could add instances of ErroInformation.

Comment: Within my Service or Validation ?